# Can you use gates without a check-in desk?

Tags: hot-springs-story

Occasionally I will see a customer reach a destination inside the hot springs by exiting the building, walking down the sidewalk, then entering nearer the destination.  This is particularly true if there is no other route to the destination.

However, all of my gates have a check-in desk attached to them.  Could I possibly expand the virtual space of my hot springs by building just gates everywhere, so that I don't have to build walkways around the outer edge of the building?

I would still have check in desks here and there so guests can check in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have gates without check-in desks.  The question is, *why would you*?  A guest has to traverse to a desk when they arrive, and on their way out.

You could technically, as you pointed out, increase the amount of space available by making the guests go around.  This space saving is mitigated by requiring extra paths on your borders.  Not to mention, the amount of time guests spend walking is time not spent spending money and generating satisfaction.